# Insert into table or update if exists multiple unique index (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm having a issue where I want to INSERT values to a table if the combination (poll_id, user_id, question_id) does not exists, else I want to update the column answer.

The table is as follows:

poll_results
poll_id - int(11) | user_id - int(11) | question_id - int(11) | answer - varchar(100)

I've set the unique to (poll_id, user_id, question_id) using:

ALTER TABLE poll_results ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_index`(`poll_id`, `user_id`, `question_id`);

When I run the following query it will first insert the first values set and then it updates the answer field with the value from the second value set.

INSERT INTO poll_results (poll_id, user_id, question_id, answer) VALUES(1, 1, 1, 'User 1'),(1, 2, 1, 'User 2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer=VALUES(answer)

**What I see is:**

poll_id - user_id - question_id - answer

1 | 1 | 1 | User 1

**What I want to see is:**

poll_id | user_id | question_id | answer

1 | 1 | 1 | User 1

1 | 2 | 1 | User 2

How can I achieve the end result?

Comment: You must have another unique index in there. Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE poll_results` to your question?

Comment: When I run the code directly in MySQL with phpMyAdmin, two records are inserted. Do you execute the code in phpMyAdmin as well?

Comment: @tadman Didn't know about that command. Found out that I actually had another unique key on the poll_id after running the SHOW CREATE TABLE query. After I deleted the unique index it worked fine!

Comment: When constructing test data for this sort of thing you should use `1,2,3` and `1,3,4` as you would've noticed a mix-up there, giving you `1,2,4` in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` feature works is on the trigger of any `UNIQUE` type indexes, not just the one you intend it to trigger on.

Remove any indexes that might be interfering with this and you should be fine.

Comment: In my case this was the problem. I didn't know I had other unique indexes specified. Thanks again!